# When is a method in Interface is 'both' overridden and implemented?

Tags: java, interface

The following code is from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/examples/CharSequenceDemo.java which I ran in netbeans in my laptop to understand Interface.

```
public class CharSequenceDemo implements CharSequence {
    private String s;

    public CharSequenceDemo(String s) {
        //It would be much more efficient to just reverse the string
        //in the constructor. But a lot less fun!
        this.s = s;
    }

    //If the string is backwards, the end is the beginning!
    private int fromEnd(int i) {
        return s.length() - 1 - i;
    }

    public char charAt(int i) {
        if ((i < 0) || (i >= s.length())) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(i);
        }
        return s.charAt(fromEnd(i));
    }

    public int length() {
        return s.length();
    }

    public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
        if (start < 0) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(start);
        }
        if (end > s.length()) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(end);
        }
        if (start > end) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(start - end);
        }
        StringBuilder sub = 
            new StringBuilder(s.subSequence(fromEnd(end), fromEnd(start)));
        return sub.reverse();
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(this.s);
        return s.reverse().toString();
    }

    //Random int from 0 to max. As random() generates values between 0 and 0.9999
    private static int random(int max) {
        return (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (max+1));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CharSequenceDemo s =
            new CharSequenceDemo("Write a class that implements the CharSequence interface found in the java.lang package.");

        //exercise charAt() and length()
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
        }

        System.out.println("");

        //exercise subSequence() and length();
        int start = random(s.length() - 1);
        int end = random(s.length() - 1 - start) + start;
        System.out.println(s.subSequence(start, end));

        //exercise toString();
        System.out.println(s);

    }
}
```

For method toString netbeans say--> method overridden and implemented but for other it just says overridden. What is the difference between overriding and implementing a method ? Aren't they same thing ?

Comment: when you override, you modify existing behavior. when you implement, you honor that existing behavior.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 5.0, @Override could only be placed on methods overriding a method defined in a super class, not one declared in an interface.  In Java 6+ you can place @Override on implementing and overriding methods.

In Java 6+ you can override without implementing

```
interface A {
    void method();
}

interface B extends A {
    @Override
    void method();
}

abstract class C implements A {
    @Override
    public abstract void method();
}

class D extends C {
    @Override
    public void method() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say "for the other it just says overridden" do you actually mean implemented?

The methods charAt, length and subSequence are marked as implemented because a) the interface lists them and b) you have added code for them (implemented them).

The toString method says overriden because the interface overrides the toString method that all Java objects have and you have also implemented it in your CharSequenceDemo.

Answer (score 0):

**implements** - You have do define every method from implemented interface

**extends** - You can use methods written in parent class

---

Implement comes from Your interface.

Override comes from Object (every java object implicitly extend Object)

Answer (score 0):

**[CharSequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#toString%28%29)** has `toString()` method, when your class implements CharSequence you class would be forced to implement toString()(thus implements), however as all the class's extend `java.lang.Object` which has `toString()` declared your class will inherit it from Object class(thus overriden).

Thus in your case

- toString() ---> implements from CharSequence
- toString() ---> overriden from java.lang.Object

Comment: so, both of them "points" to toString which is overridden. And from where can i accept that i got correct answer ?